# Using ifelse( ) to assign a variable to a tbl_df/data.frame object in R causes R to run short of memory

Tags: r, dataframe, out-of-memory, dplyr

I have a dataset with 4811616 rows, consisting of variables A, B, and C. Variable C has NAs, and I want to assign zeroes to cases that are NA. I proceed as follows:

```
df$A <- ifelse(is.na(df$A), 0, df$A)
```

And I get an error saying that R runs out of memory. It is not possible, as I am running a 64bit version of R on Windows 7 with 36Gb of memory, using `memory.limit(size=34000)` to assign memory to R, and the only object in the environment is my data frame of  128.5 Mb. Moreover,  `print(object.size(ifelse(is.na(df$A), 0, df$A)),units="MB)` returns 36.7 Mb, so it cannot be that the vector that results from the `ifelse` statement is too big.

In fact, assigning the vector to a variable `x` doesn't cause R to run out of memory. It is when I try to assign it to my `tbl_df` that the problem happens. It also happens if I assign it to a `data.frame(tbl_df)`.

Can anyone help me to uncover what is going on and to find a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(A), A:=0][]
```

If you need to replace the "NAs" in all the columns, you can use `set` which would be very efficient.

```
for(j in seq_len(ncol(df))){
 set(df, i=which(is.na(df[[j]])), j=j, value=0)
}
```

Using a bigger dataset

```
set.seed(495)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,1:5),3*4811616,
  replace=TRUE), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))
system.time(setDT(df1)[is.na(A), A:=0])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 0.026   0.002   0.027
```

Just to compare with @lukeA's method

```
system.time(df1$A[is.na(df1$A)] <- 0)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.140   0.004   0.144
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,1:5), 3*20,
   replace=TRUE), ncol=3, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))
```

Comment: It works like a charm, but could you also tell me what is behind this drainage in memory that I saw when I used `df$A <- ifelse(is.na(A),0,df$A)`?

Comment: @GuilhermeKenjiChihaya  Though `ifelse` is vectorized, it may be a bit slow and is not needed here.  Have you tried the `ifelse` on a fresh R console?

Comment: Got you. I was always taught that vectorised means good, but I see that it is not always the case.

Comment: @GuilhermeKenjiChihaya  `ifelse` is fast but there are other vectorized methods which are faster than that.  Another option is using `replace` which I guess would be faster.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate when people take the time to teach beyond just solving the problem. I'm not accepting your answer because @lukeA provided me with one that takes no additional package, but I will nevertheless vote yours up.

Comment: @GuilhermeKenjiChihaya  It is okay, but data.table assignment is by reference, which would be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
df$A[is.na(df$A)] <- 0
```